# Chrome Extension Creating HTML Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm a bit new to Google Chrome extension developing and what I need to figure is how to dynamically create a tab and add dynamically generated text onto it (just for example I want to show the user a tab with his geolocation and maybe  some nice graphics).

The create a tab part is easy :

chrome.tabs.create(..)

but how could I access and change this tab's document ?

My extension's logic is based on popup.html and my entire javascript is in a file called popup.js. I know I can access popup.html and change it (with regular DOM acccessing) but I want the new tab !

I'm suspecting there might be some duhhhh answer to this but currently I'm stuck and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the igoogle new tab page example helps wich uses chrome_url_overrides:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/examples/api/override/override_igoogle/manifest.json

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/examples/api/override/override_igoogle/redirect.html